# Is there something that behaves like .wait() and .notify() in EJB environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb

I know i must not tinker with threading in EJB Containers, therefore i do not know how to do the following thing in an EJB Environment the right way:

**Involved are**:

- Stateless Session Bean "Client"
- Stateless Session Bean "Server"
- MessageQueue "Queue"
- Message Driven Bean "Mdb" which processes messages from "Queue"
- n Stateless Session Beans W1 through Wn

**Scenario is**:

*Client* calls a Method of *Server*, which in turn sends several Messages to *Queue*. After that, *Server* does some other stuff. In the meantime, *Mdb* consumes a message, calls *Wi* which does some rather long calculation, and gets the result. Now *Mdb* gives the result to *Server*. When *Server* got all the "results" for every message it sent, it does some more calculations with the results from the *W* s, and returns that result to *Client*.

**My Problem**:

In Java SE I would simply do .wait() to have *Server* wait for the results of the *W* s, after *Server* did the work after sending the messages. Then *mdb* would .notify() when it has set the results. Since I must not tinker with threading in EJB Containers, as the specification states, I am lost cause I did not find any appropriate way to achieve the same behavior in EJB Environment.

Any help on that problem would really be appreciated, thanks in advance.

P.S.: I am working with JBoss 5.1.0, in case there are any vendor-specific measures to tackle that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate solution for this is the "request/response" pattern for messaging.  In a nutshell, you can do "synchronous" operations via messaging systems by sending a message and waiting for a response message (all of this is legal in the J2EE world).  there are a variety of ways you can achieve this in practice, but the general idea is that you send the request messages with some sort of unique identifier, then wait for response messages using a message filter set for the request id(s) that you sent (this is generally what the ["correlationId" field](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID%28java.lang.String%29) is used for).  the MDB would get the request messages, process them, and send the response messages using the specified unique identifiers from the request messages.  you can do all of this with one queue, or you can use separate request/response queues, or you can do crazy things like creating ["temporary" response queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/QueueSession.html#createTemporaryQueue%28%29) (per-request).  you can tell the MDB where to send the request messages using the [`Message.setJMSReplyTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSReplyTo%28javax.jms.Destination%29) method.

The general pattern is:

1. client calls server
2. server:

   1. creates messages, sets correlationId and replyTo
   2. creates QueueSender, sends messages
3. mdb (repeat for each message):

   1. receives message
   2. processes message
   3. sends response message with correlationId
4. server:

   1. creates message filter with correlationId
   2. creates QueueReceiver with message selector
   3. calls `receive()` until all messages are received and processed (or times out)
   4. does final processing, responds to client

(Obviously, the server proceeds directly from step 2 to step 4, i just wrote it this way to highlight the control flow.)

Comment: Ok, that is similar to what i thought about, but my biggest problem is the "then wait for response messages"-part. That is where i would use the wait-notify in SE. So i am looking for the actual waiting mechanism with MDBs. Do you have a hint on that?

Comment: @Daniel - you would be setting up a MessageConsumer and calling `receive()` on it.  that is the "wait" part of the equation.  you are not using an MDB for the final processing, only the distributed work.

Comment: Is there a possible race condition where the server misses a message from an MDB that completes before the server calls receive()?

Comment: @increment1 - with a topic yes, with a queue, no.

Answer (score -1):

what object acts as the Server that the MDB returns all the messages? it probably needs some kind of CountDownLatch to wait for, in the size of number of messages (which is changed by the MDB until reached zero). When it become zero, it will wake up can run the code that return to the client.
See the API doc for CountDownLatch.

Comment: you aren't supposed to be using things like CountDownLatch in the J2EE world, same issue as wait/notify.

Comment: I guess that is a discussion to another thread. Since J2EE is still Java - Yes you can, and if you still need to work with threads, you must design your application so it will be able to support such code.

Comment: Actually, depending on the app server, no you can't.  the spec disallows such tools, and some app servers actually enforce this through custom SecurityManagers (to the extent supported by the jvm).

Comment: not to mention that blithely ignoring the spec because it "happens to work in my test" is a great way to create code with latent bugs waiting to pop out in production.