# Using @Timeout in EJB instead of Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am hitting a webservice from my code twice. The first hit gives me a product_ID using which as a path parameter I make the second get call which gives me the response.

The problem is that the second(GET) call should be hit after 2 seconds from the first(POST) call. I am using EJB in my project and the simplest solution is using Thread.sleep(2000). But EJB does not recommend the programmer to manage threads on it's own.

In my research I have found a probable solution, but due to my lack of EJB skills I am not able to understand it much. could someone guide me to solve this issue.

The URL to the probable solution is: [Using the EJB3 timer service instead of Thread.sleep()](http://www.deplication.net/2011/07/using-ejb3-timer-service-instead-of.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your method of the first call, you should create a programmatic single action timer with a 2 second delay after the first call.

```
Timer timer = timerService.createSingleActionTimer(2000, new TimerConfig(product_ID, true));
```

When a programmatic timer expires (goes off), the container calls the method annotated @Timeout in the bean’s implementation class. The @Timeout method contains the business logic that handles the timed event.

```
@Timeout
public void handleTimerEvent(Timer timer) {
   String productId = timer.getInfo();
   someMethodWithDoSecondCallLogic(productInfo)
}
```

refs:

- [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html)
- [EE6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#bnbpa)

Comment: Does @Timeout works exactly like Thread.sleep, i.e it makes the current thread go to sleep or does it makes the process async. Because I am running my project and The second webservice is hitting after 2 seconds. But the method which should be executed after the webservice is running before that.

Comment: the @Timeout works in the background and reacts when the timer is finished that was created with `timerService.createSingleActionTimer`, if you create other timers in this EJB class then they will also trigger the @Timeout method. 
( maybe you want to use the response of the second call to use in the first method? that will of course not be possible with the Timer )

Comment: If you want response in same method you do the first call, you'd have to follow something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100987/is-there-something-that-behaves-like-wait-and-notify-in-ejb-environment